# how to rewrite mvc routes to aspx

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have home controller and Index action method. The below url works

```
http://localhost/home/index
```

Will it be possible to make it work like below

```
http://localhost/index.aspx
```

I am trying below code in Global.asax but does not works

```
routes.MapPageRoute("MyPage", "create.aspx", "~/home/create");
```

**Route Config**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapPageRoute("MyPage", "create.aspx", "~/home/create");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Customized",
        url: "{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Default", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Reports",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Reports", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Default", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use MapRoute() instead of MapPageRoute(), as you are still referring to an MVC controller/action:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default2",
            url: "index.aspx",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

PS: Remember to register the new route before other ones which may eventually interfere with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't **MapPageRoute** for non static content as you are doing. If you wan't to hide the `Controller` for your route the `Customized` already do this. If you are mixing MVC + WebForms you should fallow this guide to se how config your routes.

[How to: Define Routes for Web Forms Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668177.ASPX)